# How to read nested node in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**How to read `Firebase` child nodes directly?**

I have nodes like `Users/userId/deviceId` and I want to read `deviceId` directly at register time. I don't have `userId` to access `deviceId`.

**Note:**

I don't want to iterate whole Users Nodes because I know I can do like this:

```
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
    User user = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
    if (user.getDeviceId().equals(android_id))
    {
        //alert user
    }
}
```

But I want to make it happen in single line like `users/userId/deviceId`
or share if you have any better way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have `Users/userId/deviceId`, then you only have enough data to look up a `deviceId` if you know its `userId`.

If you *also* want to look up the device without knowing the `userId`, you'll have to add more information to your database. E.g. `Devices/deviceId/...`. With this additional data structure you can look up the data you store if you only know the deviceId.

This type of data duplication is *very* common on NoSQL databases: you model your data for the use-cases for your app. As you add more use-cases, you often end up adding some more data to the database. This is also known as denormalizing, or fanning out.

The [Firebase documentation has a page on this type of data structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data), but I also recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a single line of code. The way in which you are iterating, is the correct way for getting data from the database. Using `getChildren()` on the `DataSnapshot` object is a common practice when it comes to Firebase.